# display cascading list on a page at same time

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, drop-down-menu

I have code for cascade drop-down list, that helps in performing search.

It works perfectly fine and displays the result also, but the problem is,

When the page is loaded for the first time, First drop-down list is shown and when a value is selected from it, the second drop-down list gets displayed and after a value is selected from the second drop-down list the search is performed.

I want that both the drop down list should get displayed together when the drop down list are selecting,

However the second drop down list should hold any value in it or can be disabled(preferred) and gets enabled only when a value is selected from the first drop-down list.

index.php

```
    <body>
    <div id="container">
        <div id="body">
            <div class="mhead"><h2></h2></div>
            <div id="dropdowns">
                <div id="center" class="cascade">
                    <?php
                    $sql = "SELECT * FROM search_parent ORDER BY searchname";
                    $query = mysqli_query($con, $sql);
                    ?>
                    <label>Country:
                        <select name="country" id = "drop1">
                            <option value="">Please Select</option>
                            <?php while ($rs = mysqli_fetch_array($query, MYSQLI_ASSOC)) { ?>
                                <option value="<?php echo $rs["id"]; ?>"><?php echo $rs["searchname"]; ?></option>
                            <?php } ?>
                        </select>
                    </label>
                </div>
                <div class="cascade" id="state"></div> 
                <div id="city" class="cascade"></div> 
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="showsearch"> </div>
    <p>&nbsp;</p>
    <script src="jquery-1.11.1.js"></script>
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function (){
            $("select#drop1").change(function (){
                var parent_id = $("select#drop1 option:selected").attr('value');
                // alert(parent_id);    
                $("#state").html("");
                //$("#city").html( "" );
                if (parent_id.length > 0)
                {
                    $.ajax({
                        type: "POST",
                        url: "fetch_state.php",
                        data: "parent_id=" + parent_id,
                        cache: false,
                        beforeSend: function ()
                        {
                            $('#state').html('<img src="loader.gif" alt="" width="24" height="24">');
                        },
                        success: function (html)
                        {
                            $("#state").html(html);
                        }
                    });
                }
            });
        });
    </script>
</body>
```

fetch_state.php

```
    <?php
include("connection.php");
$parent_id = trim(mysql_escape_string($_POST["parent_id"]));

$sql = "SELECT * FROM features WHERE parent_id = '" . $parent_id . "' ORDER BY fname";
$count = mysqli_num_rows(mysqli_query($con, $sql));
if ($count > 0) {
    $query = mysqli_query($con, $sql);
    ?>
    <label>State: 
        <select name="state" id="drop2">
            <option value="">Please Select</option>
            <?php while ($rs = mysqli_fetch_array($query, MYSQLI_ASSOC)) { ?>
                <option value="<?php echo $rs["id"]; ?>"><?php echo $rs["fname"]; ?></option>
            <?php } ?>
        </select>
    </label>
<?php } ?>
<script src="jquery-1.11.1.js"></script>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#drop2').on('change', function () {
            //var fname = $(this).val();
            var fname = $(this).find('option:selected').text();
            // rename your file which include $fname  with get_search_data.php
            if (fname !== "") {
                $.post('get_search_data.php', {fname: fname}, function (data) {<!--get_search_data.php is used to perform search--->
                    $('.showsearch').html(data);
                });
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Put both the dropdowns in `index.php`, but give the second one a disabled property. Also give it a value:

```
<select name="state" id="drop2" disabled="true">
<option value="">Please Select</option>
</select>
```

Now put the following within your `$(document).ready`:

```
$('#drop1').change(function(){
    $('#drop2').prop("disabled", false);
});
```

This will disable the second dropdown until the first selects a value.
Put the JS from `fetch_state.php` underneath the rest. 
Now when you select a value, the dropdown is enabled and it is populated.

Result should look something like this:

```
<body>
<div id="container">
    <div id="body">
        <div class="mhead"><h2></h2></div>
        <div id="dropdowns">
            <div id="center" class="cascade">
                <?php
                $sql = "SELECT * FROM search_parent ORDER BY searchname";
                $query = mysqli_query($con, $sql);
                ?>
                <label>Country:
                    <select name="country" id = "drop1">
                        <option value="">Please Select</option>
                        <?php while ($rs = mysqli_fetch_array($query, MYSQLI_ASSOC)) { ?>
                            <option value="<?php echo $rs["id"]; ?>"><?php echo $rs["searchname"]; ?></option>
                        <?php } ?>
                    </select>
                </label>
            </div>
            <div class="cascade" id="state">
             <label>State: 
                <select name="state" id="drop2" disabled="true">
                <option value="">Please Select</option>
                </select>
            </label>
            </div> 
            <div id="city" class="cascade"></div> 
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="showsearch"> </div>
<p>&nbsp;</p>
<script src="jquery-1.11.1.js"></script>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function (){
        $("select#drop1").change(function (){
            var parent_id = $("select#drop1 option:selected").attr('value');
            // alert(parent_id);    
            $("#state").html("");
            //$("#city").html( "" );
            if (parent_id.length > 0)
            {
                $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: "fetch_state.php",
                    data: "parent_id=" + parent_id,
                    cache: false,
                    beforeSend: function ()
                    {
                        $('#state').html('<img src="loader.gif" alt="" width="24" height="24">');
                    },
                    success: function (html)
                    {
                        $("#state").html(html);
                    }
                });
            }
        });

         $('.drop1').change(function(){
            $('.drop2').prop("disabled", false);
         });

         $('#drop2').on('change', function () {
        //var fname = $(this).val();
        var fname = $(this).find('option:selected').text();
        // rename your file which include $fname  with get_search_data.php
        if (fname !== "") {
            $.post('get_search_data.php', {fname: fname}, function (data) {<!--get_search_data.php is used to perform search--->
                $('.showsearch').html(data);
            });
        }
    });
    });
</script>
</body>
```

Comment: sorry for replying so late, i used ur code but it is not enabling the second drop down list when value is selected from the first dropdown list. And i would also like to know that u have used dropdown1 and dropdown2 in javascript but where it has been initialized in the code. can u plz guide me more on the code

Comment: Ah yes I see I made a mistake. `dropdown1` and `dropdown2` should be `drop1` and `drop2`. I'll edit my answer as well. Does it work now?